# Unable to get SSL Settings > Require Client Certificate to work, it just gives 403 Forbidden

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

Been tearing my hair out for days on this.

First off, with SSL enabled but client certificates set to ignore, it works.

I have a valid certificate with a private key on the server.

I exported it and installed it on my client. The CA is also on both machines, the certificate is considered valid, trusted, and working.

When I set SSL Settings Client certificate 'Required', I get a 403 error.

I have tried disabling all authentication methods, creating a Local User (a member of Users, and therefore has permission to access the folder the site is located in), and then using Configuration Editor to enable OneToOneMappings and adding a single entry, with the base64 version of the client certificate, the username and password of the Local User, and everything Enabled.

Unfortunately, I still get a 403 Forbidden.

I created a c# application to check the certificate was being attached:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

var cert = GetCertificate(); // returns the certificate, I have checked it

handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

await client.GetAsync(url);
```

Same result, 403 Forbidden.

I've been googling it a while but I can't find anyone that's actually managed to get this to work.

I want to make it so that only people with the server's certificate are able to connect to it.